# Am I correctly projecting a geometry using a WKID in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system

I would like to take in any valid WKID for a spatial reference and then project a single geometry to it. The following code seems to be working, but (1.) can someone verify that this is the correct way to do this. (2) Can I just put the ProjectionHint parameter in Project5() to 0/false -- thanks

```
private IGeometry5 ProjectGeometry(IGeometry5 geom, int outSR)
{
    IGeometryServer geomServer = new GeometryServerClass();
    ISpatialReference spatialReference = geomServer.FindSRByWKID("EPSG", outSR, -1, true, true);
    geom.Project5(spatialReference, 0);
}
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Project5_Method/002m000001rz000000/
"The projectionHint parameter contains information about whether a geometry will cross the coordinate system horizons. If it doesn't, parts of the code that check this and intersect the geometry with the horizons can be omitted. This can dramatically improve performance. Use ISpatialReference3::ProjectionHint to initialize this parameter."

```
C#
public void Project5 (
    ISpatialReference newSpatialReference,
    int ProjectionHint
);
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume no geotransformation will be required?

Comment: Here's the [specs for projectionHint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000021000000), I don't see a `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the projectHint specs. I've created an SOE method with an OutSpatialReference parameter. Someone could put in any SR with a different GCS from the underlying data. Will IGeometry.Project() pick an acceptable geotransformation (even if not the best)? How does the geometry>buffer service work without a geotransformation?